# How to add "Showing 1-10 (20)" for pagination using the simplePagination jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm using the SimplePagination jquery plugin-http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/
and I was able to successfully intiate the plugin and paginate through the items.
however im trying to add a legend saying: "Showing 1-10 of 20 records" besides the 'prev' and 'next' buttons, something like this:

```
Showing 1-10 of 20 << Prev 1 2 3 Next >>
```

Is there any way i can add this legend using the simplePagination plugin??
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Your pagination plugin cleaning parent element and render it everytime when user switch page, my solution is not elegant, but working.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1yrypnL6/2/)

Btw. I not found Your plugin on CDN, so code of plugin was included on begin of `javascript` JSFiddle frame (please scroll to bottom to see my code).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="pagination-container"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.pagination-addon {
    width: auto;
    height: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    float: left;
}

.pagination-addon div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $('#pagination-container').pagination({

        items: 40,
        itemsOnPage: 10,
        //here You can set Your label title
        labelText: 'Showing',
        onInit: function (){

            var startItem = ((this.currentPage*this.itemsOnPage)+1);
            var endItem = ((startItem-1)+this.itemsOnPage);

            if(endItem > this.items){

                endItem = this.items;
            }

            $('#pagination-container').prepend('<div class="pagination-addon">'+
            '<div class="pagination-label">'+this.labelText+'</div> '+
            '<div class="pagination-start-item">'+startItem+'</div> - '+
            '<div class="pagination-end-item">'+endItem+'</div> of '+
            '<div class="pagination-total-items">'+this.items+'</div></div>');
        },
        onPageClick: function (){

            this.onInit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Mateusz Mania for the soln, however i found one issue when handling elements not in multiple of 10, viz: if there are 34 elements (instead 40) the label says: 'Showing 31 - 40 of 34' instead of 'Showing 31 - 34 of 34' ..is there any way to fix this?

Comment: No problem. Fixed. Tell me if You have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of do this, but if you really want this to work will, you should choose a different plugin. Basically, you would have to:

- store the original number of records
- create the paginator using the plugin
- create your text using the getCurrentPage() combined with the number of items per page you are using and the original # or records to figure out which records you are showing (for example, if you are on page 2, there are 20 items per page, and you have 60 items, your text would be "showing 20-40 of 60")
- add an html string to the page controls' container with your text.
- when creating the paginator, add an onPageClick callback that updates the text.

Comment: I tried the way mentioned, however i seem to face the same issue as i mentioned in the above comment...i see 'Showing 31 - 40 of 34' instead of 'Showing 31 - 34 of 34', while handling non-multiples of 10 or 20's